# Change the outcome of a variable based on a button push to match a different button

Tags: javascript, variables, button

I have a button with an id that sets a global variable like this:

```
<div class="mybuttons"    
<button id="mapOne" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#map-1-scene-1">Scene</button>
<button class="no-click-span" id="mapOneCurrent" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#map-1-scene-1"><i class="fas fa-charging-station fa2x"></i> Current</button>
</div>
```

Then in JS:

```
var mapNumber;

const mybuttons = document.querySelectorAll('.mybuttons button');
mybuttons.forEach(mybutton => {
  mybutton.addEventListener('click', processClick);
});

function processClick() {
  window.mapNumber = this.id; // the id of the clicked button
}
```

The second button in the div with the id #mapOneCurrent just reopens the modal without refreshing the data.

What I would like to happen, is if the second button is pushed (eg #mapOneCurrent) that the variable mapNumber just remains as mapOne (without the word "Current" at the end of it). So it would almost be as if the other button had been pushed.

Is this possible to do in this type of scenario?

Comment: If you're already getting the ID of the clicked button, can you just check what the ID is before setting the `mapNumber` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```js
var mapNumber;

const mybuttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('.mybuttons button')];
mybuttons.forEach(mybutton=>{
  mybutton.addEventListener('click',function() {
    window.mapNumber = this.id.replace("Current",""); // the id of the clicked button
    console.log(mapNumber);
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="mybuttons">   
<button id="mapOne" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#map-1-scene-1">Scene</button>
<button class="no-click-span" id="mapOneCurrent" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#map-1-scene-1"><i class="fas fa-charging-station fa2x"></i>Current</button>
</div>
```

However, you could simplify it by using "delegated event listening" to:

```js
var mapNumber;

document.querySelector('.mybuttons').addEventListener('click',function(ev){
  if (ev.target.tagName==="BUTTON") {  
    window.mapNumber = ev.target.id.replace("Current","");
    console.log(mapNumber);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="mybuttons">   
<button id="mapOne" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#map-1-scene-1">Scene</button>
<button class="no-click-span" id="mapOneCurrent" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#map-1-scene-1"><i class="fas fa-charging-station fa2x"></i>Current</button>
</div>
```

In this snippet the event is listening to `click`s on the wrapper container `.mybuttobs` but will trigger actions only if an inside `BUTTON` was clicked.

Comment: Thank you. It really was as simple as adding this.id.replace("Current",""); that to the code! Amazing!